# Mongodb php authentication. Where is Mongo/admin.php?

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication

I.
I'm new on mongodb, it seems cool.

For security reason I configured mongod to launch with `auth = true`.

Now, according to http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=589836, authentication §,

> To access administrative functions, you must use MongoAuth (logged in
>   to a specific database) or MongoAdmin (root access to all databases). 
>   These are not included in the built-in PHP extension, so you must
>   include or require the files Admin.php and Auth.php.  They are in the
>   downloaded source under php/Mongo/. Assuming you have php/ on your
>   include path, you can say:
>
> ```
> include "Mongo/Admin.php";
> ...
> ```

I've searched in /var/share/php, /var/share/php/PEAR, and no Admin nor Auth.php found...

1. Are these files included in a common PEAR install ?
   (assuming a common install is `sudo pecl install mongo`)
2. If no, how to install them ?

Thanks

Comment: They are in the extensions source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/master/php/Mongo - you probably have to copy them to your "local extensions" directory.

Comment: ??? Why the hell aren't they in a common pecl installation? They are indispensable for security reason!

Comment: I think it is because most peple like to split the DB admin from the App and it is considered a security problem not to since your app now has control over the server itself.

Comment: But also this is just a helper class you can actually make your own class to do this easily enough. Infact if you look here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/master/php/Mongo you will see they are nothing special, you can do all these OPs without them.

Comment: Okay, but I must authenticate even if I want to add one document to any collection of any database. That's not administration. Is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused about authentication.

By default Mongo with or without these added classes will log you in as an authenticated user.

The classes you reference to are Administration and Server control classes. They give effectively root access to everything.

Just adding a username and password to your MongoDB connection string to auth will do good enough, you don't need those classes. An example:

```
mongodb://root:awesome_password@localhost:27017
```

And that will initiate the default authentication within the PHP driver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it resolve part of my problem. Do you have a solution for http://stackoverflow.com/q/12527017/127493, please?