# Cant connect to a mongodb database user with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I've a running mongod with `auth=true` on my server.

If I log to my admin user (from the admin database), no problem to fetch data.

```
<?php
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://admin:adminpass@127.0.0.1");

$db = $connection->selectDB( "mydb" );
$collection = $db->selectCollection( "user" );
var_dump($collection->findOne());
?>
```

but if I replace the first line by

```
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://mydbadmin:dbadminpass@127.0.0.1:27017");
```

It can not connect and get an error like :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Couldn't authenticate with database admin: username [mydbadmin]' in .....
```

So the problem is `new Mongo()` try to connect my user to the admin database instead of the "mydb" database. How can I choose the database I want to connect?

**EDIT :**

according to http://php.net/manual/fr/mongo.construct.php
I tried this

```
$login = array("username" => "mydbadmin",
               "password" => "dbadminpass",
               "db" => "mydb",
               "connect" => true
);

$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost", $login);
```

but

```
Couldn't authenticate with database mydb: username [mydbadmin]' in .....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you don't specify a db in the constructor, it uses the `admin` database by default (as documented in the [`Mongo::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php)-reference). Try the following:

```
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://admin:adminpass@127.0.0.1/mydb");
```

notice the `/mydb` after the host-part, which lets the PHP-api connect to the desired database.

Comment: funny, I made an edit when you wrote your answer. About __construct documentation.

Comment: Okay, your answer works perfectly. I just wonder why my edit do not work. Any idea ?

Comment: @Martin I would make a hap hazard guess and say you tried to connect directly to mydb using the db admin credentials instead of those associated with that db. Here is an example: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-Logginginasanadminuser I believe you tried the latter there.

Answer (score -1):

check ur php driver version and mongod version, both version must be compatible..
Ex:
for mine..
im using php 5.3(wamp) and mongod 3.0 in mlab.com.. 
my dll version is php_mongo-1.6.6-5.3-ts-vc9-x86

working good for me

refer this site for mongo driver details

refer the below site 
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

refer this site for download mongod drivers
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.6/windows

thank you...
sureshapn.m@gmail.com